# What is the difference between property of Baire and Second Category in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I am reading Oxtoby's book *Measure and category*. I have a question regarding the assumptions of theoren 4.8 in there:
[image]

Here are the definitions:

**Linear set**: Any subset of $\mathbb{R}$

**Second Category**: A second category set is a set which is not of first category.

**Fisrt category**: a first category linear set is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, which is a countable union of nowhere dense sets.

**Baire property**:A linear set $A$ has the property of Baire if there is an open set  $U$ such that  $A \Delta U$ is of of first category.

**My question is:** Given that $A$ has the baire property, doesn't it imply that $A$ is not of first category, and therefore is of second category? If $A$ "differs" from an open set by a set of first category, doesn't it imply that $A$ cannot be a countable union of nowhere dense sets in $\mathbb{R}$?

Thank you!
Shir

Answer (score 2):

Every first category set has the property of Baire, because the empty set is open. When he says "a set of second category having the property of Baire", that means "a set which differs from a **nonempty** open set by a set of first category."

Comment: I see, thank you. but, then, isn't the theorem equivalent to just stating that $A$ contains an open segment?

Comment: No. To take a rather trivial example, $A$ could be the set of all irrational numbers, which satisfies both of the alternative hypotheses: it's a second category set with the Baire property, and a Lebesgue measurable set of positive measure. $A$ contains no open segment, because the rationals are dense. However, $(x+A)\cap A\ne\emptyset$ for **every** real number $x$ and you don't need the theorem to see that: it's clear because both $x+A$ and $A$ have "small" (first category, measure zero, countable) complements.

Comment: Yes, I see that now. Thank you!